# Neo4J Cypher query - Null relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am fairly new to Neo4J and have a problem in a Cypher query.

I write cypher queries through Neo4J java and my Neo4J database is designed as follows:

I have a user node with attributes such as id, name, age, email, gender and a node city. Every user is related to a city node(with attributes id, name) by a relationship (lives). However there can be a case when a user is not associated with city.

Now my scenario of the query is such that I want to fetch all details of user and the city he lives in, in a single query which is.

```
 match p, c, p-[:lives]->c where p.type = 'com.Person' and c.type='com.City' and p.id = 12345 return p.name, p.age, p.email, p.gender, c.name;
```

The query works well when user is related to a city, but it fails in case when a user is not associated with a city.

Could you please help me with a query that can handle both the scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your `MATCH` and `WHERE` clauses are actually requiring that all matched `p` must be associated with a city. You have to use the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause for optional matches.
2. By the way, the "p, c" in "MATCH p, c, p-[:lives]->c" is unnecessary and inefficient.

To get the results you want, try the following (`c.name` will be `null` if there is no associated city):

```
MATCH (p {type: "Person", id: 12345})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:lives]->(c {type: "City"})
RETURN p.name, p.age, p.email, p.gender, c.name;
```

Also, I would strongly suggest the use of the labels `Person` and `City` for your `p` and `c` nodes (instead of the `type` properties). That would make your queries much more efficient and also clearer. If you made this change to your nodes, the faster queries would look like:

```
MATCH (p:Person {id: 12345})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:lives]->(c:City)
RETURN p.name, p.age, p.email, p.gender, c.name;
```

Comment: I'm new to cypher.
In my case, using `WITH` before `WHERE` helps me to get the result i want.

`OPTIONAL MATCH` is little difficult to me yet.